# Memory managing about framebuffer texture in opengl

Tags: opengl-es

I do memory testing about OpenGL framebuffer texture on android.

Test code is as follow :

```
//Test for initialize framebuffertexture.
glGenTextures(20, texs);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[i]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, 0, 1024, 1024, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
    glFrameBufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texs[i], 0);
    glViewPort(0,0,1024,1024);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

//Test for release framebuffertexture.
glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo);
glFrameBufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0);
glBindFrameBuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
    glDeleteTexture(1, &texs[i]);
}
```

The result I saw is those textures will be a few left.(Not delete all textures.)

My question is as follow :

Q1. Is this driver behavior?

Q2. Does exist any method to delete all textures?

Comment: "*The result I saw is those textures will be a few left.*" How do you know that?

Comment: @NicolBolas  Because I work on android platform, I use sysdump meminfo pid to print vedio memory. I will dump at begin, allocate, and release. I see the vedio memory decrease after releasing. But the memory difference between beginning and releasing looks like remaining several textures.